# What is the sefer עץ אבות

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, search

In Rav Emden's pirush of perek shirah, זמרת הארץ, he references a sefer or pirush called עץ אבות.

Where can I find the sefer as well as the specific point of reference within this sefer? It's concerning צפרדע being a compound word of צפר דע on the first line of the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA/gTbzkd0zAO8C?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I saw that but wasn't sure if that's the right sefer. Also, would you know where this concept is mentioned?

Comment: Wait what’s a צפר

Comment: It appears to be an edition of Pirkei Avot published by Rabbi Emden with 3 specific commentaries, the Bartenura, Lechem Shamayim and Lechem Nikuddim. Here is a link: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45093&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Comment: @CuriousYid Although it could be read as “bird”, it most likely is referencing the soft light of morning, like in the expression צפרא דשבתא. That דע alludes to the softening of harsh judgement because 74, gematria of דע, also refers to the sweetened judgment in the name אכדטם, which also has a gematria of 74. So the plague of צפרדע is a compound word actually meaning צפרא דאכדטם, a softer judgement. That the plagues started lighter and became increasingly more severe.

Comment: @YaacovDeane do you have a source for that ?

Comment: @Shababnik A source for what?

Comment: @YaacovDeane your above comment

Comment: @Shababnik Do you see what is written in the זמרת הארץ commentary? He’s introducing principles of how to understand Hebrew. His first is by looking at the associated gematria and the second is the general Hebrew grammar idea that words of greater length than 4 letters are to be considered compound words. צפרדע is a 5 letter noun. The rest is looking at the meaning of the component words in relation to the general compound word which is the 2nd of the 20 plagues. The reference to his book on Avot is referencing chapter 5:4 from Avot.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I can't seem to find the reference in 5:4. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Shababnik In the edition linked from the Grapke via google, it also includes a commentary from the Gra. That should help you to zero in on the specific section. The Gra actually focuses on the plagues.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, I must be missing something... Do you know where the zimrat Haaretz's reference is in the sefer eiz avot ?

Comment: @Shababnik I only glanced at the Google link above after reading the text photo in the question. I knew that ten plagues were mentioned in Avot 5:4, saw their elaboration from the Gra in Eitz Avot. My guess from Rav Emden is that it is probably a grammatical reference in the Lechem Nikkudim portion of his commentary on Avot, but you might have to read carefully to longer, Lechem Shemayim. Sorry I can’t be more helpful. I’ll try to take a look at it later today.

Comment: @Shababnik I came across a different sefer that you will find helpful in understanding what Rabbi Emden is talking about. It is called: ספר פרקי שירה - מספרים תהלות יי by Rabbi Chananiah of Monselice. He has an entire discourse about the term צפרדע. You can find it at hebrew books.org